# how to re-enable javascript click-defeating mechanisms?

Tags: javascript, click

I got myself involved in helping a friend with a woocommerce dynamic gallery of photos she wants to sell.  My thought was, it will be easy to modify the thumbnail view of the gallery to link to the actual product (rather than the .jpg).  It was, relatively easy.

But now I find that clicking on the link does not call the product page.  I believe the click is being defeated somewhere, but I haven't learned sufficiently well yet how to read the mass of code, nor even where to attempt debugging.  I tried a dom breakpoint on the href being modified, but don't see my answer.

Could you advise how to re-enable the normal click processing?  I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".a3dg-thumbs-static ul li a").on("click", function( e ){ alert "hello");return true; });
})

// class_wc_dynamic_gallery.php,  line 510 modified to provide link to product page ('sted jpg) 
</script>
```

but no click interception -- the selector is `#gallery_1104_6420 > div.a3dg-nav > div.a3dg-thumbs.a3dg-thumbs-static > ul > li > a`

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap with setTimeout. It is hack, but could help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   setTimeout(()=> {
       $(".a3dg-thumbs-static ul li a").on("click", function( e ){
          alert("hello");
          return true; 
       }); 
   }
});
```

Also there was syntax error in you example - alert without brackets, may be editor ate it.

Comment: Neither the alert with parens nor the timeout made any difference.  Something's still eating the click events.  Thanks for the suggestions, I appreciate whatever may help ...

Comment: My selector wasn't activating, due to stupid misspellings like $ instead jQuery.  The solution is:  jQuery(document).ready(function ( $ ) {
    $("div.a3dg-thumbs.a3dg-thumbs-static > ul li > a").click(function(e) {
          window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    });
});